# Tangency Point of Incircle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Is there is a general formula for tangency point of incircle $\triangle{ABC}$ on triangle $\triangle{A}BC$ especially for right triangle

Answer (score 2):

I think what you might be looking for is the Gergonne Point of a triangle. Wikipedia has a good explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Gergonne_triangle_and_point). The tangency points are given in trilinear coordinates(perpendicular distances to vertices A,B, and C) like so:

$$T_A = 0 : \sec^2(\frac{B}{2}) : \sec^2(\frac{C}{2}) \\
T_B = \sec^2(\frac{A}{2}) : 0 : \sec^2(\frac{C}{2}) \\
T_C = \sec^2(\frac{A}{2}) : \sec^2(\frac{B}{2}): 0$$

Where A,B,C are the relevant angles.